# System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object

Tags: c#

I'm calling invoking a jar file with the code

```
Process process = new Process ();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar test.jar" + Filename;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.Start ();
process.WaitForExit ();
```

but only on some windows with windows 7 the process is invoked correctly but I get the exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No process associated with the object.
in System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState (State state)
in System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState (State state)
in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle (Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
in System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit (Int32 milliseconds)
in System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit ()
```

on windows 10 it works

maybe patch problems on windows?

thank you

Comment: You should verify first whether it was able to be started before you attempt to wait on it.

Comment: thanks, but because on windows 10 it works while on some windows 7 it doesn't?

Comment: Is java installed (and on the path) on all machines you're running this on?

Comment: Java is installed in fact the jar file runs correctly both on windows 7 and on windows 10 with a difference that on windows 7 raises the exception

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
Process process = new Process ();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar test.jar " + Filename; //add space after .jar
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.Start (); //process instead of Process
process.WaitForExit ();
```

Comment: but because on windows 10 it works while on some windows 7 it doesn't?